# Copy a Binary, Big endian, Short integer 2D matrix into a numpy array of dimensions (time, Y, X)

Tags: python, numpy, binary

I have a Binary, Big endian, Short integer 2D matrix of size (1000,1750). This is a IR data file and I need to copy this into a numpy array of dimensions (time, Y, X). Any help is highly appreciated. I used the code below to read it, and knew the size and format from another source.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import os 
import matplotlib
fname='.../bghrus1407150015.bin'
varsave = np.fromfile(fname, dtype = '>i2')[-1750*1000::]
varsave = np.reshape(varsave,[1750,1000],'F')
plt.imshow(varsave.transpose())
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of time, Y and X?

Comment: The data is in the file, and you haven't loaded it yet?  How does the file specify the shape?  or is that something that you just know from other sources?  If it is just data bytes, you might be able load it with `np.fromfile` and reshape it after.  You may have to try different dtypes (e.g. `np.dtype('>i4')`).

Comment: - I have a file named IR  consisting of 48 .bin files which are half an hourly IR data for a certain day. 
The names are like this: bghrus1407150015.bin, bghrus1407150045.bin, bghrus1407150115.bin, bghrus1407150145.bin and so on..

Comment: How can **a file** consist of 48 files?  Are you able to load each of these .bin in the manner of your last edit?